Azure Linux Web App host disk space more than 90%
There is an Azure Web App on Linux that uses a container. It has 90% Host Disk Space. And there is no way to clean up images like docker image prune. The container itself has 2.5gb of host disk space. I've tried downgrading and upgrading the plan, didn't help.

I downgraded and upgrade the service plan, which freed up 2GB.
Cleared all logs in the container.
Insights logs are disabled.
File logs are enabled with a 35MB limit and 1-day retention.
Cleared manifests in ACR.
Restarted the Web App.
Reduced the image size from 3GB to 1.5GB.

After all these actions, the result is:
Filesystem                                                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                                                                49G   41G  5.6G  89% /
tmpfs                                                                                  64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm                                                                                    62M     0   62M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1                                                                              49G   41G  5.6G  89% /temp
/dev/sda3                                                                              63G   14G   47G  22% /appsvctmp
devtmpfs                                                                              4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev/tty
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                                                 2.2G     0  2.2G   0% /sys/firmware

Uses du -sh /*:
(app-3.12) root@41312aw235g:/app# du -sh /*
160K    /appsvctmp
0       /bin
4.0K    /boot
0       /dev
3.0M    /etc
4.0K    /home
0       /lib
0       /lib64
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot read directory '/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/146/task/146/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/task/146/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/146/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       /proc
80M     /root
32K     /run
0       /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
8.0K    /tmp
306M    /app
1.2G    /usr
262M    /var

How can I clean this up? I believe the space is being taken up by image manifests, but I don't have access to clean them up.
